# AngularJS translate not working

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a problem. I found AngularJS translate [example](http://embed.plnkr.co/o16dpI/) on internet and tried to apply on my MVC app. And it doesnt work and I still dont get why. I tried simple app like HelloWorld and it works, but If I just add translate lib like this:

```
app.controller("about", ["$scope", "$translate", function ($scope, $translate)
```

... AngularJS stoped working.

I tried the simle check test and created simple web on my desktop: `index.html`, `app.js`. And guess what? It works. So doesnt that mean that there is some problem with MVC? If it is, and dont know where.

Comment: You got any errors in console? Please add the error log.

Comment: Check that you haved added `angular-translate.js` to your project and added `'pascalprecht.translate'` to your `app` declaration